# Highcharts - Range Selector - Date fields not visible

Tags: highcharts

[image]I am using Highcharts 4.2.5. 
The Range Selector is partially displayed. The from & to date boxes are not displayed, but sometimes if i enlarge the page , i see the date fields, but the date field is readonly. One more observation, i see the date field if the chart width is big. But with multiple line charts the date does not come.

[image]

[image]

Below is my options

```
{
"tooltip" : {
    "useHTML": "true",
    "headerFormat" : "{point.key}<br>"

},

"credits" :  {
    "enabled" : true
},
"navigator" :{
    "enabled": true
},
"scrollbar" :{
    "enabled": true
},

"rangeSelector" :  {
    "allButtonsEnabled" : true
}, 

"legend" :  {
    "enabled" : true
},
"title" : {
    "text" : ""
},

"series" : []
}
```

Comment: can you give the link to js fiddle / codepen so that we can help you better.

Comment: This is replicable in the http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/     note that, if you reduce the frame size the date box disappears, but if you expand it comes back.

Comment: Hi ZEE, it is normal that sometimes input fields are not visible - it is because they starting to overlap with buttons. Do you want to have these input fields always visible? You can use rangeSelector.inputEnabled: true in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Input shows when the chart has enough space, otherwise the input hides. If you want to force input to be always enabled, you need to set it in options.

```
rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            inputEnabled: true
        },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bnmb05eu/

Comment: i did enable "inputEnabled" : true, but the from and to date box is readonly.

Comment: the box in your example is not readonly, but it is in readonly mode in mine. when i click on the box, it does not work. I have added a new screenshot, where you can see the from date box overlapping, and its readonly.